# How to compare string of list with a string of list in presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

My column is String(), I tried:

```sql
WHEN column = '[1]'
```

it didn't work as the desired rows with column equals to '[1]' didn't get returned, but then I tried:

```sql
WHEN column = CAST('[1]' AS VARCHAR)
```

it worked... I'd really like to know if the latter one is indeed the right way to do this..

Comment: _"it didn't work, but then I tried:"_ - can you please elaborate? How exactly it did not work?

Comment: Sorry it was badly paraphrased. It didn't work as it didn't return the rows with the column equals to '[1]', but it did work when I used the ^ above mentioned trick